# Updating download progress bar into notification area from AsynTask

Tags: android, notifications

I have implemented Async Task into Service. Here is the initializing of Progress Notification, that I am calling from `onPreExecute`.

```
mProgressNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    CharSequence tickerText = "Download";

    mProgressNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());
    context = this.getApplicationContext();

    Intent mNotificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityClass.class);
    PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mNotificationIntent, 0);
    //mProgressNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mProgressNotification.flags = mProgressNotification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    CharSequence title = "Downloading initializing...";
    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.noti);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, title);
    contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 0, false);
    mProgressNotification.contentView = contentView;
    mProgressNotification.contentIntent = mPendingIntent;
    mProgressNotificationManager.notify(STATUS_BAR_NOTIFICATION, mProgressNotification);
```

After that in `doInBackground` , I have implemented my download procedure, and after that I am updating download progress,

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);

        int mDownloadProgress = progress[0];
        // Log.d(TAG,"AsyncTask : download In progress");           
        CharSequence title =  "fileName" +":  "  + mDownloadProgress + "%";
        mProgressNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, title);
        mProgressNotification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100,
                mDownloadProgress, false);
        mProgressNotificationManager.notify(STATUS_BAR_NOTIFICATION, mProgressNotification);            

    }
```

It is working fine.. updating properly, but issue is that, Notification bar is hanged. I can not up-down notification bar. I want to update notification bar like downloading any application from Google market (Play) .

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

What appears to be happening is that you are replacing the notification meaning that there is a new notification to show.

What you need to do is update the notification and not replace it.

Have a look at this :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating