# Android: download file from server and show the download progress in the notification bar using AsyncTask

Tags: android, download, notifications, android-asynctask

I am using this [example](https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/) to download a file from a server using `AsycTask` and to show the downlaod progress in a notification bar. I just modified the `doInBackground` method in order to downoad my file:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... Urls) {
        //This is where we would do the actual download stuff
        //for now I'm just going to loop for 10 seconds
        // publishing progress every second
        try {   
            URL url = new URL(Urls[0]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( _context.getFilesDir() + "/file_name.apk");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count ;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();      
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create the notification in the statusbar
        mNotificationHelper.createNotification();
    }


protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // The task is complete, tell the status bar about it
        mNotificationHelper.completed();
    }

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // This method runs on the UI thread, it receives progress updates
        // from the background thread and publishes them to the status bar
        mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(progress[0]);
    }
```

Everything is going ok except that I cannot pull down the notification bar. Why?

Comment: Could you please post your onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods?

Comment: Thanks. ill take a look. have you tested it on a different device, or on the emulator? It seems a very weird problem imo.

Comment: Tested on different devices, always the same problem.

Comment: can you please put an sleep(1000) method before publishProgress and check. just a guess.

Comment: related question (also unanswered):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256229/android-updating-download-progress-bar-into-notification-area-from-asyntask?rq=1

Comment: why do i need to put sleep (1000)? Cannot solve the problem without the sleep?

Comment: @ b.i please try and tell me whether its working or not.

Comment: When I put sleep(1000), this doesn't mean that the download is slowing down?

Comment: i know that very very very well it will slow down and putting a sleep is not a right solution. i just want you to try . def putting a sleep is not a solution for sure.

Comment: @ abbas: yes, it works, but the download is slowing....

Comment: Can we see your mNotificationHelper?

Comment: @ iPaulPro: the NotificatiocHelper is from this link: https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/

Answer (score 4):

Following is picked from the comments.

> can you please put an sleep(1000) method before publishProgress and
>   check. just a guess

-

> yes, it works, but the download is slowing

Hope you understood the problem. Since you are updating the Notification bar very frequently, you cant be able to pull it down. By increasing the chunk size of data or by updating the progress bar on every 4 or more kb instead of 1kb, you can avoid this problem.

Above will not slow down the data download.

Comment: totally agree. There is no use in notifying the progress that much. I would probably use a 16kb buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You should override [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) method to update your UI.

Comment: I am doing that:   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //This method runs on the UI thread, it receives progress updates
        //from the background thread and publishes them to the status bar
        mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(progress[0]);
    } ....But the problem is that I cannot pull down or up the notification bar.